# Syntax error at or near "=" on postgresql update query

Tags: postgresql

I have created update query :I'm getting error as **error: syntax error at or near "="**.I have posted the entire API . There are 2 querys in 1 API ,table_name value is passed from one query to another
I don't understand my mistake.

```
table_name = abc
status_id = 111
spf_id = 1
```

PUT Method API :

```
router.put('/update', function(req, httpres, next) {
  console.log("Inside");

 const role_id = Role_id.Role

  console.log("Inside the update api",role_id);

  console.log("stage 1")
  pool.query("SELECT  table_name FROM roles WHERE role_id="+role_id+"")
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log('success 1st query',data)
      table_name = data.rows[0].table_name;
      console.log("table_name: ",table_name)
    })


    const spf_id = req.body.spf_id;
    const status_id = req.body.status.status;
    console.log("Inside the update 2 api",spf_id,status_id,table_name);
  pool.query("UPDATE "+table_name+" SET status_id ="+status_id+" WHERE spf_id ="+spf_id+" ")
  .subscribe(
           data => {
               console.log('success 2nd query',data)
            }, err => {
           console.log('error',err)
          //  httpres.send('error');
       })

});
```

Comment: Can you explain why you're doing `UPDATE "+table_name+"` instead of `UPDATE abc`?

Comment: Yes its giving. Is it necessary that table name must be inside quotes?

Comment: @GMB no it's not necessary

Comment: Value of table_name is coming from other query.I have just given example .Actually its table_name = data.rows[0].table_name;

Comment: Most likely one of those variables contains empty string. Did you try to output to log/console your query before executing it?

Comment: Yes I tried ,I'm getting values for all variables

Comment: Can you show the actual query that's being executed? The one in your question looks like the client-side version of it before the variables are replaced by actual values.

Comment: Its not taking table_name

Comment: OK that's much better; by leaving out the initial quotes, it looked like the table name was in quotes, when it was actually the rest of the query in quotes. So: what data type is `spf_id` in your table? If it's a TEXT or similar type, you will need single quotes around the value: `spf_id ='"+spf_id+"' "`

Comment: What kind of script is that? It does not look like pure SQL to me. And what triggers the error message? The script execution or the SQL server? Additionally, can you share the full and exact error message which should also contain the line throwing it?

Comment: Got my mistake . its done :)